# Passing host ip to Docker container when running docker compose file on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Host ip can change, so I need to pick IP address dynamically. I've found some solutions online for dockers running for Linux, but I can't find how to do it if you run docker container on Windows. Running it through docker compose file.